# Why won't my my furnace stop running unless I shut it off at the breaker?

Tags: furnace

I can't get my furnace to shut down unless I turn off the breaker.

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Had something similar happen with a gas fired boiler a few years ago. Turned out to be a relay that stopped working. Have warranty with local utility and they came out and replaced it.

Comment: Is it heating, or is just the blower fan on? If it's just the blower that is running, and the burners are not firing up.  The most likely cause is an open limit switch.

Comment: Does it continue to produce heat after the thermostat as satisfied, or does only the blower run continuously? Also please provide make and model of furnace.